# What is the best answer about using a word as the difference?

Tags: word-usage

What is the best answer about using a word as the difference?

If someone ask me like what are they difference?
So I reply like this " they are not much different" .
Is this good answer or is there any sentence wrong?

Comment: Please allow at least a day or two before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one right away. For info about why this is helpful, please see [“Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)”](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Answer (score 1):

Someone might ask "what is the difference between A and B?" or "are these things very different from each other?". You could answer that "there is not much difference between them" or perhaps "they are not very different from each other", or even "they are very similar" or perhaps "they are identical".